# How to run .exe files output by Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, exe, turbo-c++

I wrote a program in Turbo C++, and compiled it there. Everything was successful, and the program ran as expected. Now, I want to run the program as an exe file. I found the exe file in a separate folder named 'Source'. But whenever I try to run it, I get the error :
"This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher."
 None of the exe files in that folder are working, although all the other softwares (like Photoshop) are opening fine.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Please don't use Turbo C++. C++ has changed dramatically since the release of that compiler, and you won't be learning any kind of modern C++.

Comment: It's a DOS executable. Most modern versions of Windows don't support running those. Please consider a C++ compiler that's not 20 years old. Visual Studio Community Edition is free and quite good.

Comment: @crashmstr's advice is good and you should follow it. However, you can run this .exe under DosBox if you really want to. Use a more modern C++ compiler to learn, though.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes on this one. The question is clear, answer is short, it's definitely on topic etc. Is it because some want to punish people who admit using Turbo C++ (usually because forced by their school or something like that)?

Comment: Btw, I wonder if someone knows how Turbo C++ itself runs the .exe. Does the whole thing run in DOSBOX or something? ag_dhruv, you might want to check the shortcut (or bat file or whatever) for the IDE, and see if you can *copy it*, and modify the copy to run your exe, if you want to be able to start the .exe from Windows directly.

Comment: @hyde: It still can be executed in x86 OS.

Comment: @Mykola As I understand the question, the IDE itself, and the program running under the IDE, are being executed in the same machine, where directly running the program .exe doesn't work.

Comment: @hyde: I think OP created executable on x86 OS or something like this.... Who knows?

Comment: @crashmstr Thank you so much for your suggestion. As has been correctly pointed out, I am forced to use Turbo C++ because that's what our school teaches us C++ in. Anyhow, I will sincerely consider your advice.

Comment: @hyde how do I modify the copy?

Comment: Shortcuts can be edited by right clicking for context menu, then selecting Properties from there. Bat files and such can be edited with text editor.

Comment: @ag_dhruv I learned C++ with Turbo C++, but that was close to 25 years ago. The standard has moved on but Turbo C++ has stood still. Plus, if your school *does* require it, then *they* should be where you go for support.

Comment: @ag_dhruv Turbo C++ is (arguably) fine for learning programming, and many programs written with it can be easily converted to compile on modern C++ compiler (except for screen manipulation or graphics). Just remember that "good" modern C++ is very different, and you can and should do many thing in a very different (shorter, safer, etc) way. You are being taught programming, not really C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OS on your PC probably is 64 bit. So the older 16 bit application would not run on it. I suggest you to use some virtual machine with installed OS DOS (or free [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/) for example), or try to compile your program on more modern compiler.

Answer (score 0):

write 
system("PAUSE");
before return 0;